# XNA 4.0 + VS2010: Symbols not loaded

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, symbols, xna-4.0

I've recently installed XNA Game Studio 4.0 along with  the Phone Development tools to play with XNA/WP in my VS2010 installation.

All is fine, altough I cannot get VS2010 to load symbols for , e.g: XNA assemblies.

I'm using also a VS2008 SP1 installation side-by-side with no symbols configured in the IDE but via env vars (since I occasionally need to use WinDbg).

My local symbol path is setup as:

`_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

VS2008 SP1 works very well caching all symbols to the specified folder.

However, cannot make it work in VS2010. Looking at the target symbols folder, I found a FailedLoads folder with a lot of text files containing "PDB NOT FOUND".

VS2010 Modules window shows many 'Cannot find or open PDB' files for Microsoft.Xna.* assemblies.

I didn't find *anything* in Google or MSDN forums.

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: _NT_SYMBOL_PATH is working for me with VS2010.  I don't think symbols for the XNA assemblies are available.  Try deleting all symbols and starting again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe XNA 4.0 symbols are not available now, and that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume no public symbols available from MS, :P.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through a similar problem, although by now probably most people have upgraded to VS 2012.

[Why is VS 2010 ignoring _NT_SYMBOL_PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981030/why-is-vs-2010-ignoring-nt-symbol-path/18069443#18069443)