# Why is VS 2010 ignoring _NT_SYMBOL_PATH?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

Does VS 2010 handle symbol file resolution differently than other MS products?
Repro steps:

1. Open control panel and make sure _NT_SYMBOL_PATH is set to something valid, like SRV*C:\DebugSymbols*\buildserver\Builds\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
2. Open a minidump file with **windbg** or **VS 2012** => debugger **succeeds** loading symbols
3. Open the same minidump file with **VS 2010** => debugger **fails** to find symbols
4. Open the Options dialog inside VS and set the debugging symbols path to the same one above.  (This setting will be saved when you close VS.)
5. Open the same minidump file with **VS 2010** => debugger **succeeds** loading symbols

This repro's on all machines in our dept.  Setting the path manually is a one-time operation and it's fine on a dev box, but it's a major pain in the lab where the VMs are constantly reimaged.

Does 2010 use additional environment variable(s) that other tools don't?

Does VS have a master settings file,  which is overridden by each user's CurrentSettings.vssettings?

Answer (score 1):

After much asking around and scouring the web, I found out from a reliable source

> _NT_SYMBOL_PATH is an environment variable that is consumed by the same component VS uses to load symbols, but is not used by VS.

I believe this comment is specific to VS 2010 (unconfirmed).  I am unable to reproduce the issue in VS 2012.

It's related to another more common issue where VS will ignore the local cache, causing performance problems, even though it's set in _NT_SYMBOL_PATH.

The workaround is to set the path manually inside VS 2010, or (better yet) open the crash dump in VS 2012.